# Compare datetime function cypress

Tags: cypress

I have a form in which a user is allowed to enter the date range and the output will have results form that particular date alone.

I am able to input the date to the form using .type() function. However, I am not sure how to check if the results are within the range specified.

For example, if the typed date is ('17/03/2019') I should be able to check if the results in the table are within the range using a code like this,

```
cy.get('.table')
  .should('not.contain','18/03/2019') // This is wrong
```

I want to compare and see if the results produced are only between 17/03/2019 00:00:00 and 17/03/2019 11:59:59.

Is this feature available in Cypress? Can somebody help, please?

Thanks,
Indhu.

Answer (score 5):

Just to keep everyone posted on the solution arrived at [Cypress Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress). The question is originally answered by [Mr. Gleb Bahmutov](https://twitter.com/bahmutov)

This validation can be handled by **Cypress.moment**, where `moment.js` library has parsing and comparison methods for date/ time.

```js
// the time in the element should be between 3pm and 5pm
const start = Cypress.moment('3:00 PM', 'LT')
const end = Cypress.moment('5:00 PM', 'LT')

cy.get('.utility-moment .badge')
  .should(($el) => {
    // parse American time like "3:38 PM"
    const m = Cypress.moment($el.text().trim(), 'LT')

    // display hours + minutes + AM|PM
    const f = 'h:mm A'

    expect(m.isBetween(start, end),
      `${m.format(f)} should be between ${start.format(f)} and ${end.format(f)}`).to.be.true
  })
```

Related document addition: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-kitchensink/pull/225