# Failure to compare dates in seconds on Cypress in ascending order

Tags: laravel, datetime, automated-tests, cypress

I have problem comparing with dates in cypress.

I have these dates

[image]

which are ordered in ascending order and the witness must demonstrate this.

With cypress I launch this test which compares that the dates are sorted in ascending order:

```
var time = 0 
var time_prev = 0   
cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
                if (index == 0){time_prev=0}
                time = Math.round(new Date($e.text()).getTime() / 1000)
                assert.isBelow(time_prev, time, 'previous date is below actual')
                time_prev = time
            })
```

The test fails with the following error:

[image]

But as you can see from the first image, the second date is smaller than the third date.

I also notice that this test fails when I run multiple tests together.

Comment: I suggest to not use round - because JS is not the best mathematician. 

On the point of doing tests together - try separate the test case in its own file, so you can be sure no other case interferes with it.

Comment: @bigeyes If you create two arrays one is created by pushing the each elements. Now we sort the same array and save it a new array. And then compare both of them, if they are same, all good, if not we throw an error, Is this something that can solves your use case ?

Comment: @AlapanDas I just need to show that the dates are in ascending order. only that and the purpose of the test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a good cypress solution for [comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272549/compare-datetime-function-cypress) and [moment comapring dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22600856/moment-js-date-time-comparison), and a possible solution

```
var time = 0 
var time_prev = 0   
cy.get('#hometable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(6)').each(($e, index, $list) => {
                if (index == 0){time_prev=0}
                time = $e.text()
                expect(Cypress.moment(time).isAfter(Cypress.moment(time_prev)).to.be.true;
                time_prev = time
            })
```

Comment: each
function(){}
TypeError
time.isAfter is not a function
cypress/integration/e2e_new_processing.spec.js:78:37
  76 |                         if (index == 0){time_prev=0}
  77 |                         time = $e.text()
> 78 |                         expect(time.isAfter(time_prev)).to.be.true;
     |                                     ^
  79 |                         time_prev = time
  80 |                     })
  81 |.

Comment: I editted the suggestion - the links provide other solutions too

Comment: ReferenceError
moment is not defined

Comment: I don't understand how to define moment

Comment: It is defined as cypress utility https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/moment.html#See-also. Try using Cypress.moment on the places I used moment